# How to implement a type constraint on a generic struct in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

I want to be able to put type constraints on a generic struct in Rust.

Here is some pseudocode explaining how that might look:

```
struct OrderedFloat<T>
    where T is f64 or f32
{
    value: T
}
```

The intended purpose is to provide `impl Ord` for this structure.

I do not want to `impl Ord` for `f32` and `f64` directly, this may break other behaviour.

The syntax above is not valid and it is pseduocode. It does not compile.

Even the following does not compile:

```
struct OrderedFloat<T>
    where T = f64
{
    value: T
}
```

If I understand correctly, this would never work, because `where` constraints apply to *traits not types* and `f64` is a type.

I would suggest this behavior might be possible to implement if there was a concept of a trait which says "X is f64-like" and "X is f32-like".

Such a trait might be what is called a "marker trait".

I am not particularly familiar with this area of Rust programming, so I don't know if these ideas are heading in the right direction or whether this is not a realizable solution.

Comment: Yes, adding a marker trait is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you could do:

```
struct OrderedFloat<T>
    where T: MyMarker
{
    value: T
}

trait MyMarker { }
impl MyMarker for f32 {}
impl MyMarker for f64 {}

fn main() {
    let f: f32 = 3.14;
    let _of = OrderedFloat { value: f };
}
```

The above makes use of a so called "marker" trait.

Comment: Wow so easy - thanks, didn't realize it was this simple